# Bot conversation reference issue

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I've got an issue with my proactive bot.

My problem is that when I add the bot to a team for the first time it fires and event which creates the team and General channel.

My issue is that it doesn't create a chat reference for other existing channels prior to adding the bot.
If I add a new channel to the team it fires an channelCreated event and a new conversation reference is created.
I have overridden OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync and as mentioned it works when first adding the bot and then if new channels are added.

Anyone know what is best practice when adding the bot for the first time? Should I just create conversations references for all existing channels when the bot is added the first time?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you just want to be able to have the bot message all channels. If that's not the case, let me know and I'll edit the answer.

I recommend taking a look at the [`Teams - Start New Thread in Channel` Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/58.teams-start-new-thread-in-channel).

Basically, you need to [have the bot get a list of Channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=dotnet#get-the-list-of-channels-in-a-team):

```cs
public class MyBot : TeamsActivityHandler
{
    protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        IEnumerable<ChannelInfo> channels = await TeamsInfo.GetTeamChannelsAsync(turnContext, turnContext.Activity.TeamsGetTeamInfo().Id, cancellationToken);

        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"The channel count is: {channels.Count()}");
    }
}
```

And then you can [send a Proactive Message to the channel by creating the conversation and then continuing it](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/58.teams-start-new-thread-in-channel/Bots/TeamsStartNewThreadInTeam.cs#L33):

```cs
var conversationParameters = new ConversationParameters
{
    IsGroup = true,
    ChannelData = new { channel = new { id = teamsChannelId } },
    Activity = (Activity)message,
};

ConversationReference conversationReference = null;

await ((BotFrameworkAdapter)turnContext.Adapter).CreateConversationAsync(
    teamsChannelId,
    serviceUrl,
    credentials,
    conversationParameters,
    (t, ct) =>
    {
        conversationReference = t.Activity.GetConversationReference();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    },
    cancellationToken);


await ((BotFrameworkAdapter)turnContext.Adapter).ContinueConversationAsync(
    _appId,
    conversationReference,
    async (t, ct) =>
    {
        await t.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("This will be the first response to the new thread"), ct);
    },
    cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  The issue is that I have a bot and I have a app.  When adding my app to a team/channel the bot gets a event and calls OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync where I create the conversation reference.  If my app gets added to another existing channel there is no event sent to the bot.  So I'm thinking if I need to create the conversation reference myself or if there is something I'm missing.

Comment: But as you kind of mention in your answer I could just get all channels in the team when the app/bot is added to a team the first time and create conversation references for each. This is so I can send proactive messages later to team members.

Comment: @OskarJenssonFjeld That's correct. You only get the event once because you get it when you add the bot to a TEAM, not to a channel. A team can be composed of many channels, so once the bot gets added to the team, it gets access to all of that team's channels, so that's when you want to query for all of the channels.

Comment: @OskarJenssonFjeld Were you able to get this working with my answer? If so, please "accept" and upvote it so others can quickly find the answer and I can clear this from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!